# ckeditor onchange - почему мой код срабатывает 2 раза?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Здравствуйте. Настраиваю ckeditor. Скачал плагин onchange (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/onchange). Подключил его в config.js:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';
```

Написал в config.js вот такой код:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    editor.on('change', function() {
        console.log('zzz');
    });
});
```

И теперь когда я что-то пишу в своем редакторе, zzz выводится дважды. Почему так? Должен же один раз выводиться.

Comment: Я посмотрел. Если нажимать shift, ctrl то событие будет одно при отпускании клавиши. Судя по всему первое событие реагирует на ввод символа, а второе реагирует на отпускание клавиши. Также событие возникает при перемещении курсора мышки над полем редактирования.

Comment: Я разобрался, в чем проблема. Строка

    config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';

не нужна.

Comment: Не знаю. Даже без неё всё равно два раза вызывается.